# Insert some column values from a table and some are manually

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables and want to insert some column values from ane table and some from through php code.
This is my query

```
INSERT INTO login2 (id, uname, pass, pid) SELECT id, uname, pass from `login`, '2'
```

But it gives an error of mysql. Plz help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incorrect.
Correct query is :

```
INSERT INTO test2 
        (id, 
         uname, 
         pass, 
         pid) 
(SELECT id, 
        uname, 
        pass, 
        '2' 
 FROM   `login`)
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO test2 
  (id, 
             uname, 
             pass, 
             pid,
    (SELECT id, 
            uname, 
            pass, 
            '2' 
     FROM   `login`) )